# Transforming CRS to UTM using Python

Tags: python, coordinate-system, utm, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to transform CRS to UTM using a GeoJSON file.
This is what I tried:

```
from sentinelhub import CRS
country_crs = CRS.UTM_32N
country = country.to_crs(crs={'init':CRS.ogc_string(country_crs)})
country.plot()
country.crs
```

But this code results in a completly wrong transformation followed by a warning message:

```
C:\Users\ASUS\Anaconda3\envs\ASV\lib\site-packages\pyproj\crs\crs.py:53: FutureWarning: '+init=<authority>:<code>' syntax is deprecated. '<authority>:<code>' is the preferred initialization method. When making the change, be mindful of axis order changes: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/gotchas.html#axis-order-changes-in-proj-6
  return _prepare_from_string(" ".join(pjargs))
```

trying this:

```
country = country.to_crs("EPSG:22391")
country.plot()
country.crs
```

resulted in the following: (negative values in the Y-axis):
[image: EPSG:22391]

Comment: Does this work `country = country.to_crs('EPSG:XXXX')`?

Comment: Yes it did. But I am not sure why the Y-axis has negative values in it

Comment: The warnings message says: `When making the change, be mindful of axis order changes: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/gotchas.html#axis-order-changes-in-proj-6`. It might explain this behaviour.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: @s.k that's right. But that warning appeared before I used your solution. When I used your solution the projection was correct but I still got negative values on the Y-axis.